# Undeclared Identifier: Probably a very simple fix

Tags: visual-c++, variables, mfc, undeclared-identifier

Language: Visual C++, MFC

I'm attempting to make an array of pointers to CString variables that I have declared in my header file. In general, this is what I'm doing:

```
CString *variableArray[5] = {
      &var1
    , &var2
    , &var3
    , &var4
    , &var5
};
```

For whatever reason, though, I keep getting the following error:

```
Error   1   error C2065: 'var1' : undeclared identifier     18  
Error   2   error C2065: 'var2' : undeclared identifier     19
Error   3   error C2065: 'var3' : undeclared identifier     20  
Error   4   error C2065: 'var4' : undeclared identifier     21
Error   5   error C2065: 'var5' : undeclared identifier     22
```

I'm not quite sure I'm getting this error. To me knowledge, this is the correct way to make an array of pointers. Any help would be awesome!

EDIT: Here are the declarations in the header file:

```
public:
CString var1;
CString var2;
CString var3;
CString var4;
CString var5;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where do you create "variableArray"?  If it's in a static method or outside the scope of the class, it would make sense why you're getting that error.

Comment: This was it. I didn't realize that it wasn't within the class. Duh. Thanks!